# Possible solutions for testing environment settings, dependencies on client machines

Tags: testing, configuration, environment-variables

I've been trying to find a method, or piece of software that can quickly automate tests of correct configuration and setup of user environments on client machines.

Tests include that users have expected AD access to particular shares, that shares are mapped correctly, that ODBC DSNs are set and datasources visible, that particular applications are installed and local configurations are correct, correct printers installed etc etc...

So far I've been writing a list of tests in NUnit, breaking every rule about not testing external dependencies in the process, but that's exactly what these tests need to do and this isn't really a program.

The idea is that the user can run this to determine what their issue might be (config file missing, server down, incorrect AD membership) and reduce time required to determine the root cause of an issue.

Has anyone come across a better way to run these sorts of tests?

I look forward to your responses.